# Byte count mismatch when re-interpreting float32 array as uint8 array

Tags: javascript, arrays, uint8array

We intend to change the JavaScript representation of an array of `float32` values to an array of `uint8` bytes. It's implied that doing so might help us more efficiently transfer the data over HTTP requests.

To do so, we have tried:

```js
var vertexBuffer = ...; // Float32Array
console.log('vertex buffer =', vertexBuffer);
console.log('vertex buffer byte length = ', vertexBuffer.byteLength)
var arr = new Uint8Array(vertexBuffer);
console.log('converted to Uint8Array: ', arr);
console.log('Byte length = ', arr.byteLength);
console.log('Byte length / 4 = ', arr.byteLength / 4);
```

The logs are:

[image: Console logs]

## Implication

The Size of `Float32Array` is `84942` and that's the same for the resulted `Uint8Array`!

Meaning each `float32` value is converted to a single `uint8`! Which is not what we intend to do! Right?

We intend to interpret each `float32` as four `uint8` values. How can we do so in the most efficient way? The change of interpretation shouldn't require any computation, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's implied that doing so might help us more efficiently transfer the data over HTTP requests.

That's not the case unless you really do wish to truncate the precision of the floating-point values to 8-bit integers. Simply send the `vertexArray.buffer` (an ArrayBuffer), the "raw data" of the array, over by any method you like. (Of course you can compress the data before sending it, if that's your jam.)

You can then reconstruct a `Float32Array` of an `ArrayBuffer` you receive by passing it to the `Float32Array` constructor.

To demonstrate these conversions:

```
> arr = new Float32Array([Math.sqrt(2), Math.sqrt(3)])
// An array of 2 floats, 4 bytes each
Float32Array(2) [1.4142135381698608, 1.7320507764816284, buffer: ArrayBuffer(8), byteLength: 8, byteOffset: 0, length: 2]

> bytes = new Uint8Array(arr.buffer)
// The same floats but interpreted as 8-bit values (8 integers, 1 byte each)
Uint8Array(8) [243, 4, 181, 63, 215, 179, 221, 63, buffer: ArrayBuffer(8), byteLength: 8, byteOffset: 0, length: 8]

> bytes[1] = 123
// Modifying the byte array 
// (since an ArrayBuffer is just opaque memory, it can't be modified,
//  but we can modify the byte interpretation of it)
123

> new Float32Array(bytes.buffer)
// (this step is not strictly necessary; 
//  modifying `bytes` will have changed the underlying buffer
//  used by the original `Float32Array` since we didn't copy it)
// Reinterpreting the modified bytes as floats 
// (see how the first value has slightly changed)
Float32Array(2) [1.4178451299667358, 1.7320507764816284, buffer: ArrayBuffer(8), byteLength: 8, byteOffset: 0, length: 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful =) Are there any out-of-the-box JS tools to compress the `ArrayBuffer` before sending it over HTTP? Just curious :)

Comment: None are in the JS standard library that I'm aware of. https://www.npmjs.com/package/lz4 is somewhat popular.